# Cannot push to a XIB iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib, gesture-recognition

In my app I tried to push to a XIB using a `long tap` event. I did the following code,

**In viewDidLoad**

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)]autorelease];
longPress.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
[longPress requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
```

and **longPress method is**

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {
ProductDetailViewController *vc = [[[ProductDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductDetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Long Press");
}
```

}
I have a XIB named `ProductDetails.xib` and I set the `File's Owner` of it as `ProductDetailViewController`.

When I'm running this code `NSLog` is working. But it's not going to the `ProductDetails.h`. And also There are no errors. How can I fix this? Anyone can help me with this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the xib hooked up to the controller, you can achieve that with the following.

```
ProductDetailViewController *vc = [[[ProductDetailViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Is it possible the navigationController is nil? If not, try to delete the ProductDetailViewController and re-add it, when you add it,include the xib file.

Comment: navigation controller is nil.

Comment: Then you should make a navigation controller programmatically or just embed your controller in a navigation controller if using storyboard.

Comment: How can I initialise it programmatically?

Comment: You can add the navigation controller in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.